# Can not resize multiple images in PHP

Tags: php, image, resize

I am trying to upload various images into a dynamically created folder on my server, then take each image and resize it while uploading it into the folder as well creating a new image and a new name.. example: image.jpg (original image) and image-resized.jpg (being the thumbnail image).

The thing I can not figure out is how to resize all images. I am not sure if I should put it in a loop. All I need is for each image I upload (could be 5 a time). It loops through and resizes them all and not just a single image. Here is my code any help would be appreciated!

Code to create folders and move picture into those folders:

```
// Desired folder structure
        $structure = './Fotos/'.$newfolder;

        // To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
        // to mkdir() must be specified.

        if (!mkdir($structure, 0, true)) {
        die('Failed to create folders...');
}else{
    $placefoldername = mysql_query("INSERT INTO datefolders (FolderDate) VALUES ('$newfolder')") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<div class=\"success\">El folder fue agregado con exito.<input type=\"button\" name=\"close\" value=\"X\" class=\"close\" /></div>";
    }}

// ...

    }

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $FolderDate = $_POST['fecha-folder'];
    $FolderName = $_POST['FolderName'];
    $hour = $_POST['hour'];

        // Desired folder structure
        $structure = './Fotos/'.$FolderDate.'/'.$hour.'/'.$FolderName;

        // To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
        // to mkdir() must be specified.


        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileupload']['name']);$i++) {
            $names = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$i];
            $target_path = "Fotos/".$FolderDate."/".$hour."/".$FolderName."/";

            $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$i]); 

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
             $success = 1;
```

Code to create a smaller (resized image) and also place into the already created folder:

```
$img = $names;   
        $imgPath = $structure;


        function resizeImage($img, $imgPath, $suffix, $by, $quality)
{
    //Create a thunbnail image by resizing the picture
    // Open the original image.
    $original = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imgPath/$img") or die("Error Opening original (<em>$imgPath/$img</em>)");
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("$imgPath/$img");

    // Determine new width and height.
    $newWidth = ($width/$by);
    $newHeight = ($height/$by);

    // Resample the image.
    $tempImg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight) or die("Cant create temp image");
    imagecopyresized($tempImg, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height) or die("Cant resize copy");

    // Create the new file name.
    $newNameE = explode(".", $img);
    $newName = ''. $newNameE[0] .''. $suffix .'.'. $newNameE[1] .'';

    // Save the image.
    imagejpeg($tempImg, "$imgPath/$newName", $quality) or die("Cant save image");

    // Clean up.
    imagedestroy($original);
    imagedestroy($tempImg);
    return true;
}
$resize = resizeImage($img, $imgPath, "-resized", 23, 100);
```

Comment: Is your function declaration actually in the foreach loop or was that a copy/paste error? If it's in the loop, then you're going to run into a double function definition error.

Comment: Mistake!! Just took it off :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you defining the function `resizeImage` in the `for` loop? It is being redefined every time the loop iterates. This could be part of the problem. Define the function outside the loop and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry I just took it off.. it was simply something I was playing with, forgot to take it off before posting.

Comment: I figured it out!!! I need to take the function out of the for loop and then just call the function inside for loop. Thanks anyway everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you can try;

when your first image proccess end use `imagedestroy()` then second image will proccessed.

Comment: I am already using imagedestroy on the original image and temp image.. should I also add this to $img and $imgPath?? Thanks so much!